# select subset of dataset based on one column

Tags: r

I have a dataset with 2 columns

```
                           text  created
    1                   cant do it with cards either 1/2/2014
    2                   cant do it with cards either 2/2/2014
    3                            Coming back home AK 2/2/2014
    4                            Coming back home AK 5/2/2014
    5                                 gotta try PNNL 1/2/2014
    6 Me and my Tart would love to flyLoveisintheAir 5/2/2014
    7 Me and my Tart would love to flyLoveisintheAir 6/2/2014
```

How can I get subset the dataset, based on the unique string of first column?

```
                           text  created
    1                   cant do it with cards either 1/2/2014
    3                            Coming back home AK 2/2/2014
    5                                 gotta try PNNL 1/2/2014
    6 Me and my Tart would love to flyLoveisintheAir 5/2/2014


structure(list(text = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("cant do it with cards either", 
"Coming back home AK", "gotta try PNNL", "Me and my Tart would love to flyLoveisintheAir"
), class = "factor"), created = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 4L), .Label = c("1/2/2014", "2/2/2014", "5/2/2014", "6/2/2014"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("text", "created"), class = "data.frame", row.names =  c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `duplicated` and `!`. Consider `df` is your data.frame.

```
> df[!duplicated(df$text), ]
                                            text  created
1                   cant do it with cards either 1/2/2014
3                            Coming back home AK 2/2/2014
5                                 gotta try PNNL 1/2/2014
6 Me and my Tart would love to flyLoveisintheAir 5/2/2014
```

Comment: Hi, I got this error "reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 7688 rows" and when I check my dataset, there are still duplicated strings in the text column

Comment: @user3456230, did you assign the output to anything? The *warning* you got simply means that R isn't going to print all of the rows in your console.

Comment: Nope, I didn't assign the output. Data_edited_txt[!duplicated(Data_edited_txt$text), ]               What should I do now?

Comment: Assigning means `newData <- Data_edited_txt[!duplicated(Data_edited_txt$text), ]`, now your new data.frame is assigned to `newData`

Answer (score 0):

there is a lot of possibilities:

```
tab[!duplicated(tab$text),]
# with dplyr
filter(tab, !duplicated(text))
```

hth

Comment: Hi, I got this error "reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 7688 rows" and when I check my dataset, there are still duplicated strings in the text column. I tried both methods but the number of rows remained the same as the original file

Comment: just save the output in other object: tab2 <- tab[!duplicated(tab$text),] or tab2 <- filter(tab, !duplicated(text)) or you can directly replace the first data.frame by the new one: tab <- filter(tab, !duplicated(text))